# How to create a column based on presence of values in other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a rather inconvenient data set that looks like this:

```
sample_df <- tibble::tribble(
                              ~project,     ~01_2020,   ~05_2021,    ~07_2020   
                                "Mark",       "1000",     "7000",       "N/A",     
                                "Boat",        "N/A",     "8300",       "N/A",       
                            "Delorean",       "8400",     "1050",       "N/A",      
                               "Parix",        "N/A",      "N/A",      "4100",
)
```

The columns, whose names represent months, contain sums for the given projects in the given months. What I need is **two** new columns: `c("time", "sum")`. The first column should represent months if there was an entry  *in the months 01.2020 through 10.2021*, and the column "sum" should contain the respective entries' sums. The desired output should look like this:

```
 project      time     sum 
  Mark     "01_2020"   1000
  Mark     "05_2021"   7000
  Boat     "05_2021"   8300
Delorean   "01_2020"   1050
  Parix    "07_2020"   4100
```

Comment: Hi @user000. This is in essence a simple reshape from wide to long, with some minor post-processing & cleaning (removing all `"N/A"` rows etc.). Please note that your sample data is not reproducible and throws an error.

Comment: After fixing your input data, `sample_df %>% pivot_longer(-project, names_to = "time", values_to = "sum") %>% filter(sum != "N/A")` does the job. You probably want to convert entries in the `sum` column to `numeric`.